# Simplification of a Quadratically constrained, Quadratic objective (to apply Semidefinite relaxation)

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, relaxations

I came up with the following optimization problem:

$$\arg\max_{G_i} \quad G_1^TI^TIG_1 + ...+G_N^TI^TIG_N$$
subject to:
$$\|G_i\|_2^2=1 \quad \forall i$$
$$\|G_i-G_{o_i}\|_2^2\leq c \quad \forall i$$
$$|G_i^TG_j|\leq\epsilon \quad \forall i,j,i\neq j \quad$$ 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} G_i(j)=0 \quad \forall i,j,i\neq j \quad$$ 
where $G_i \in R^n$.

Is there any way to somehow factor out $I^TI$ and convert it to semidefinite programming problem? how could I use semidefinite Relaxation for this problem?

I tried to use semidefinite relaxation, but the second and third constraints are hard to deal with for me:

Let:
$$C=I^TI, X_i=G_iG_i^T$$

Now we can rewrite the problem as:
$$\arg\max_{X_i} \quad \sum_{i=1}^{N} tr(CX_i) $$
subject to:
$$tr(X_i)=1 \quad \forall i$$
$$X_i\succeq 0 \quad \forall i$$
$$Rank(X_i)=1 \quad \forall i$$
$$\|G_i-G_{o_i}\|_2^2\leq c \quad \forall i$$
$$|G_i^TG_j|\leq\epsilon \quad \forall i,j,i\neq j \quad$$ 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} G_i(j)=0 \quad \forall i,j,i\neq j \quad$$

But I don't know how to rewrite last two constraints based on $X_i$.
Update: Let $[G_i\;1]^T$ as the new variable for the problem, the second constraint could be homogenized. But still the third and forth constraints, I don't know how to write them based on new variable.

Update:

Let $x_m = \begin{pmatrix} G_m \\ t_m \end{pmatrix}$ and $X_m=x_mx_m^T$, now we can rewrite the problem as follows:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname*{argmax}_{X_m} \sum_{m=1}^{M}tr(CX_m) 
\end{equation}
subject to:
\begin{equation}
tr(X_m)=2 \;\; \forall m
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Rank(X_m)=1 \;\; \forall m
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_m \succeq 0 \;\; \forall m
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
tr(\begin{pmatrix} I & G_{0m} \\ G_{0m}^T & 0 \end{pmatrix} X_m) \leq c(epochs)-G_{0m}^TG_{0m}   \;\; \forall m
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
tr(\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \frac{I}{2} \\ \frac{I}{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
X_m)=0 \;\; \forall m
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
tr(\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0} & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
X_m)=1 \;\; \forall m
\end{equation}

Now Just the orthogonality constraint remains. In fact, I don't need $G_i$s to be orthogonal, I just want they are different.

Comment: What exactly is $I$?

Comment: Your problem is the nonconvex quadratic equality constraint and the final nonconvex bilinear constraint, not the objective which is a convex quadratic

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $I$ is a $m*n$ matrix, so $I^TI$ has the dimension $n*n$

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks, but why $\|G_i\|^2$ is nonconvex equality constraint? it seems convex to me. For the last one, it is kind of orthogonality constraint, is there any way to convert it to the convex constraint?

Comment: Draw the feasible set for the constraint $x^2 = 1$ where $x$ is a scalar...

Comment: and no, these are intrinsically nonconvex sets

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks, yes you are right, but as far as I know, if I could convert this problem to minimization over vectors, I can use semidefinite relaxation for solving that.

Comment: Semidefinite relaxations are used to compute upper bounds of the objective, but you will not (typically) solve the problem.